# local variable in Flash Builder 4.5

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder, flash-builder4.5

I have two scripts in a View, one script is inside a Component. 
In the Component script I need to add numbers from data as they are added to a list and then display the total in a label placed in the View.
If I declare the variable in the first script, the Component script can't see it and if I declare it in the Component Script the label can't see it.
How will I declare it so that everyone in the view can see it?
Thanks,
Kim

Here is the code, the problem is where should I place the var MyTotal so it can be used anywhere in the view:

```
<s:view
     <fx:Script>
          <![CDATA[
                  //if I place it here the next CDATA inside IconItemRender can't see it.
                  private static var MyTotal:Number=0;
          ]]>
     </fx:Script>
     <fx:Declarations>
          <s:CurrencyFormatter id="usdFormatter" useCurrencySymbol="true"/>
     </fx:Declarations>
        <s:itemRenderer>
           <fx:Component>
               <s:IconItemRender ..............>
                  <fx:Script>
                     <![CDATA[
                              //if I place it here the Label "TotalAmountLb" can't see it.
                             // and it get reset to 0 everytime I call the function getInvoiceAmount.
                             private static var MyTotal:Number=0;

                             private function getInvoiceAmount(item:Object):String
                             {
                               MyTotal = MyTotal + Number(item.Amount);     
                             }
                    ]]>
                  </fx:Script>
               </s:IconItemRenderer>
            </fx:Component>
         </s:itemRenderer>
      </s:List>
      <s:Label id="TotalAmountLb" text="{usdFormatter.format(MyTotal)}"/>
  </s:view>
```

Comment: I think your question doesn't make any sense. first make your question clear.

Comment: Please explain more clearly, and show some code.

Comment: if i understand this right, you should give a id for your component. With an id, you can refer variables inside component. Other way is the dispatch custom event from component to view.

Comment: I tried to give the Component the id "MyId" and then added MyId.MyTotal. Then I get an error 1119

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution, I had to add [Bindable] before the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this: 
Declare `MyTotal` in first script.
 And in component script just try to access with `outerDocument.MyTotal`

Comment: No, I get an error saying: 1178: Attempted access to inaccessible property MyTotal through a reference with static type views

Comment: @KimHJ think you have to declare `MyTotal` to `public` or `protected`